# Installed package docker-compose-plugin but can only start it from /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose [solved]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, docker, docker-compose

I installed docker-compose through

`$ sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin`

and as I see by the output of `dpkg -L docker-compose-plugin`:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/libexec
/usr/libexec/docker
/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins
/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/docker-compose-plugin
/usr/share/doc/docker-compose-plugin/changelog.Debian.gz
```

it is installed to `/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose`

Should I not install it through the package `docker-compose-plugin` ?

Obviously the terminal doesn't find it there. Is this really the correct way to install docker-compose? And if so, how do I make the binary available to my system, for example such that it is also found by the `which` command.

I can only run it with the whole qualified path `$ /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose`

Btw why is it obviously installed to a folder (`/usr/libexec/`) where the system doesn't seem to look for the binary?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to https://docs.docker.com/compose/#compose-v2-and-the-new-docker-compose-command docker-compose when installed via the package docker-compose-plugin is the new version 2 and is to be started without the hypothen so

instead of
`$ docker-compose up`

you would issue

`$ docker compose up`

**The hyphen is replaced by a whitespace !**